# R Programming - (ggpubr) How to add a legend to annotate the central tendicies?

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am currently working on coding and I've wanted to create a histogram which shows the mean and median of a dataset. However, I have no way to convey to the viewer which of these lines stand for the mean and the median.

How could one add a legend and edit the titles to be able to convey these to the viewer?

Dummy Code:

```
library(correlation)
library(ggpubr)


data("iris")

PL <- gghistogram(iris, x = "Petal.Length", bins = 8,
                  color = "black", fill = "#c68ed1",
                  title = "The Length of the Petals",
                  xlab = "Length of the Petal (cms)",
                  ylab = "Amount of Petals")

PL +
  font("title", size = 14, face = "italic") +
  font("xlab", size = 12, face = "bold") +
  font("ylab", size = 12, face = "bold") +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = mean(iris$Petal.Length)), col = "#f50018", size = 1) +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = median(iris$Petal.Length)), col = "#2128ab", size = 1)
```

[Histogram Produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W0Rbd.png)